# HLS to RTP multicast FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I want to transmit HLS stream to RTP multicast via FFmpeg and use the following command:

> ffmpeg -re -i HLSstream -c copy -f rtp_mpegts rtp://ip:port

But the output source сrumbles sometimes (I can't understand periodicity of it). I playing it via VLC and it shows the following errors:

> [00007fe17800b508] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS
>   discontinuity (received 7, expected 2) for PID 0
>
> [00007fe17800b508] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS
>   discontinuity (received 7, expected 2) for PID 4096
>
> [00007fe17800b508] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS
>   discontinuity (received 8, expected 7) for PID 17
>
> [00007fe17800b508] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS
>   discontinuity (received 2, expected 14) for PID 0
>
> [00007fe17800b508] ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS
>   discontinuity (received 2, expected 14) for PID 4096

It works well when I copy the HLS stream to local file and play it. 
Is the way to fix it? Or please advice other tool to transmit HLS to UDP.

Comment: RTP/UDP is a lossy protocol. You should expect lost packets.

Comment: ok. thanks! I routed output from ffmpeg to vlc2 with the following command:
ffmpeg -re -i HLSstream -c copy -f mpegts - 2>/dev/null | vlc - --ttl=255 -I dummy --sout '#rtp{access=rtp,mux=ts,dst=IP,port=PORT}' :sout-all :sout-keep
And it works without errors. In previous variant I saw crumbles each 5-40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best variant, but in my case it helped. I getting data with ffmpeg then routing output to vlc2 via pipe and transmitting it to rtp with the following command:

> ffmpeg -re -i HLSstream -c copy -f mpegts - 2>/dev/null | vlc -
>   --ttl=255 -I dummy --sout '#rtp{access=rtp,mux=ts,dst=IP,port=PORT}' :sout-all :sout-keep